# Why can I group `cmd` and `/c` in one quotes pair?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

`cmd` can be grouped with `/c` between the same pair of quotes.

```
C:\>"cmd /c" echo 1
1

C:\>"cmd.exe /c" echo 1
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>"cmd /c"echo 1
 1

C:\>cmd /c"echo 1
1


C:\>c"md /c"echo 1"
 1
```

I noticed that `cmd.exe` cannot be quoted in that way, and if there is no space between the closing quotation mark and the command, a leading space is supplied.

How are the quotes parsed?
Some basic information that might help: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133/)

---

#### Update：

When I copy another program which prints its command-line arguments to the working directory and rename it to `cmd.exe`, I found they are calling two different executables.

```
C:\>cmd /c echo 1
...calling my program...
arg0 is <cmd>
arg1 is </c>
arg2 is <echo>
arg3 is <1>

C:\>"cmd /c" echo 1
1
```

And the leading space is related to the number of quotes.

```
C:\>"cmd /c"echo 1
 1

C:\>"cmd /c"e"cho 1
1

C:\>"cm"d /c"echo 1
1

C:\>"cm"d /c"ech"o 1
1

C:\>"c"m"d /c"echo 1
 1

C:\>"c"m"d /c"ech"o 1
1

C:\>"c"m"d" /c"echo 1
1

C:\>"c"m"d" /c"ec"ho 1
1

C:\>"c"m"d" "/c"echo 1
1

C:\>"c"m"d" "/"c"echo 1
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.685]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>exit
```

Comment: I've tried `"C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /c" echo 1` and it gives `The directory name is invalid.`

Comment: @phuclv, it's likely because the `/` in `/c` is interpreted as path separator, leading to a directory name `cmd.exe ` with a trailing space, which is not allowed…

Comment: Besides the fact that `"cmd /c"echo 1` seems to work, it's also quite interesting that it returns a space in front of the `1`…